# Joining data where timepoint is within a interval

Tags: r, lubridate

Would not mind to see other solutions, but I also dont understand why I get incomplete and wrong answer. (lubricate::interval gets wrong)

For example is del_time[1,] not in the interval of times[3,]. The objective is to join "status" to del_time where the timepoint is withing a interval.

Example data:

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

ti <- now()

times <- tibble(time1 = c(ti + 3600, ti + 7200, ti + 10800, ti + 14000),
                    time2 = time1 + 3599, status = c("One", "Two", "Three", "Four"))

del_time <- tibble(time = times$time1 + 1750)
```

Code:

```
FUN1 <- function(x,y){

  x <- ymd_hms(x)
  which_int <- x %within% interval(start = y[[1]], end =  y[[2]])
  out <- as.character(y[which_int, 3])
  return(out)
}


del_time$status <- apply(del_time[, 1], 1, FUN1, y =  times)
del_time
```

Comment: You could also take a look at [beetwen](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.5.0/topics/between) from `dplyr`

Comment: Regular user of %between% from data.table, did not know dplyr had its version, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is:

```
which_int <- x %within% interval(start = ymd_hms(y[[1]]), end =  ymd_hms(y[[2]]))
```

However, I would not mind alternative solutions.